# How to return a random number in javascript which is always greater then the previous number

Tags: javascript

How can I return a random number in javascript which is always greater then the previous random number every time the code reruns. For example when the code runs first time it returns 1000 and then when it runs second time it returns 1300.

Conditions: The number must always be an integer.

Answer (score 7):

```
function randomFunction() {
  var x = 0
  return function() {
    x = x + Math.round( Math.random() * 100 )
    return x
  }
}

var nextRandom = randomFunction()

nextRandom() // => 51
nextRandom() // => 127
nextRandom() // => 203
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
function myRnd(prev, max) {
    return prev + Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
}

var last;
last = myRnd(1000, 500);
last = myRnd(last, 500);
```

**EDIT**

Being inspired by [@dimakura](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426097/dimakura)'s outstanding answer, here is my closure-based function which accepts start value and next max random step:

```
function myRndFunc(baseValue) {
    return function(max) {
        baseValue += Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
        return baseValue;
    };
}

var myRnd = myRndFunc(1000);
myRnd(300);
myRnd(500);
```

Comment: `max` seems like something of a misnomer here... given that you have the potential to exceed the `max` by adding `prev` to the random number.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply adding the previous number?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    newR = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + oldR); 
    //  use newR here.
    oldR = newR;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Conbine `Math.random()` with `Math.floor()` setting the minimum end of your range to the last result.

```js
var min = 0;
var max = 10000;
$("#randomise").click(function() {
  var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  $("#result").text(result);
  min = result;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
<button id="randomise">Randomise</button>
```